# Uninstalling Ubuntu when it is on the Windows partition

Tags: wubi, uninstall

I partitioned my hard drive in order to install Ubuntu on one half and have Windows 7 on the other. However, when I went to install Ubuntu, I selected install alongside Windows 7 thinking it would give me the option to select a partition to install it to and it did not. It, apparently, just installed it on the partition with Windows 7. From what I have found about uninstalling Ubuntu, I should see a partition created by Ubuntu on the Drive and I do not.

[screenshot http://i1128.photobucket.com/albums/m497/ezekielstyles/diskmanagement.jpg](http://i1128.photobucket.com/albums/m497/ezekielstyles/diskmanagement.jpg)

*Note: The Ubuntu (U:) partition is the one I created to install Ubuntu, it does not actually have Ubuntu installed, note that the partition is empty.

Comment: dead link so we have no useful info

Answer (score 1):

That screen shot is blurry and I can not tell, but from what you describe, did you install wubi ?

If so , see : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation

To install Ubuntu into it's own partition, you burn the iso to a CD, and then re-boot. A common mistake is to make a Data CD (copy the files to a CD rather then burning an image).

See:

[Ubuntu wiki burning iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)

[Ubuntu Wiki install guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)

Comment: I can't edit my first post due to being new and there being an image, but I tried to add in that I Used LinuxLive USB creator to install Ubuntu. Hopefully this image is a little more clear. [![screenshot][1]][1]

*Note: The Ubuntu (U:) partition is the one I created to install Ubuntu, it does not actually have Ubuntu installed, note that the partition is empty.

 [1]: http://i1128.photobucket.com/albums/m497/ezekielstyles/diskmanagement-2.jpg

Comment: Thank you , that picture is much clearer. Looks like you installed via wubi, see my answer above for how to proceed.

Comment: I followed <a href="http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/nongeeks-guide-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-dualbooting-machine/">this</a> guide to uninstall Ubuntu and reached <img src="http://i1128.photobucket.com/albums/m497/ezekielstyles/thispoint-1.png" alt="this"/> point. I then restarted to see if everything was going as planned at which point it told me that Win7 needed a repair. I loaded the OS disc and repaired. Win7 is working but I'm not sure if Ubuntu was uninstalled successfully and completely. So now I'm not sure if the Wubi uninstall isn't working because it's already uninstalled or if I killed it

Comment: And I apparently don't know how to make hyperlinks

Comment: The first link I gave you review this for you in detail. Do you see ubuntu in the list of installed programs (as in the link)? Is the ubuntu disk on your windows drive ?

Comment: No it's not in my list of installed programs and I installed via flash drive. But considering I can find no trace of Ubuntu anywhere, I will assume it has been successfully uninstalled. Thank you for your help. :-)